# Are there any way to 'cancel' or 'reject' to show AlertView when the specific push notification is received?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a question about the APN(Apple Push Notification) and have as below;

### Question

Are there any way to 'cancel' or 'reject' to show `AlertView` when the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is invoked?

### Background of this question

I'm developing iOS app which has APN feature. 
This application receives pushed messages from my provider server.

The provider server sends various text messages written in 1 of 3 languages(English, Japanese and Chinese).
In addition, my app is required to receive messages written in specific language selected by device only like below examples;

- If your device selects "English" and the push server sends English message like "Check it out!", then my app have to show the message as usual.
- However, if your device receives Japanese text message, my app have to keep silence without showing `AlertView`.
  In this case, the messages should be shown on only iOS devices which selects Japanese.

I knew that we can check the "loc-key" property to detect language, but I couldn't find the method to 'cancel' showingAlertView.

Thus I asked the above question.

I appreciate if you share your idea to solve this issue.
Thank you,

Hidehiko

Answer (score 0):

This is doable, but not at the iphone level, it should be done in the server side, you will need to send the language that the devices uses to the server,

For example device a uses english and device b uses japanese

Now when you push an english notification, the server will filter out all japanese devices

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Please let me clarify 1 point;

Is that method stated in the 
"Passing the Provider the Current Language Preference" in the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW3)?